# How can you set AnimateLayoutChanges to True via C# in Xamarin.Android?

Tags: c#, android, animation, xamarin.android, android-linearlayout

How can you set AnimateLayoutChanges to True via C# in Xamarin.Android for a linear layout? I cannot use an xml resource file when building this custom view. The xml for this linear layout would be this:

```
       <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:minWidth="25px"
            android:minHeight="25px"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
            android:id="@+id/linearLayoutOne"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
```

All of the other attributes can be set via C# via the following:

```
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MatchParent, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WrapContent, 1);
        linearLayoutOne = new LinearLayout(Context);
        linearLayoutOne.Orientation = Orientation.Vertical;
        linearLayoutOne.LayoutParameters = layoutParams;
        linearLayoutOne.SetMinimumHeight(25);
        linearLayoutOne.SetMinimumWidth(25);
```

So how in the world do you set AnimateLayoutChanges in C#?

Answer (score 0):

The C# equivalent of setting that is:

```
linearLayoutOne.LayoutTransition = new LayoutTransition();
linearLayoutOne.LayoutTransition.EnableTransitionType(LayoutTransitionType.Changing);
```